# How does django implement existence check

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

For the following query:

```
res = People.objects.all().exists()
```

What exactly is django doing, using a mysql backend? Is it the following:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM people')
results = cursor.fetchall()
if results:
    res = True
else:
    res = False
```

Or, does it use something more uptimized, such as:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT 1 FROM people')
if cursor.fetchone():
    res = True
else:
    res = False
```

Comment: Why don't you examine the query itself? Either use `connection.queries` in the shell, or use the Django debug toolbar in your app.

Comment: @DanielRoseman could you please show me how I'd profile this in the view code using `connection.queries` ?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper `exists().query` would not work. `exists()` return a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django always tries to optimize [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) query. In case of `mysql` it uses `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT 1 FROM people LIMIT 1
```

As Daniel noted in comments, you can explore the underlying queries made by Django by viewing `connection.queries`:

```
from django.db import connection

res = People.objects.all().exists()
print connection.queries
```

See more information at [How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

FYI, `has_results()` method in [`django.db.models.sql.Query`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L430) class is responsible for constructing the `exists()` query.